# MySQL query keeps doing LIMIT 1

Tags: php, mysql

This query here is supposed to SELECT * pages where the $_GET['variables'] match the conditions.  The `$_GET['variables'] are $page_type = type of page AND $loc = location to search`.  The problem is that I have it set to LIMIT 20, but it only renders one page.

```
function SearchByTypeLoc($page_type, $loc) {
  $query = mysql_query("
    SELECT 
      `$page_type`.title AS title,
      `$page_type`.url_title AS url_title,
      `$page_type`.page_type AS page_type,
      `$page_type`.street AS street,
      `$page_type`.city AS city,
      `$page_type`.state AS state, 
      `$page_type`.city_state_zip AS city_state_zip,
      `$page_type`.phone AS phone,
      LEFT(`$page_type`.body, 100) AS body,
      LEFT(`$page_type`.type, 50) AS type,
      GROUP_CONCAT( i.image_loc ) AS images
    FROM `$page_type` 
    JOIN page_images i USING( title )
    WHERE
      `$page_type`.page_type = '$page_type' AND
      `$page_type`.city = '$loc'
    ORDER BY title
    LIMIT 20");

while($fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) { ...

?>
```

Any idea how to make it not LIMIT 1?

Comment: what do you mean by "renders one page"?

Comment: On a search page, it selects a teaser of each page.  So if $_GET['loc'] is set to 'Chicago', it will get all the titles of * places in Chicago.  But, it's only getting one title.

Comment: what have u tried? you should open console and execute an actual query. how can we guess where is an error

Comment: so in other words your query returns only one record?  and it's supposed to return more than one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GROUP_CONCAT is an aggregate function,
try explicitly add a

```
GROUP BY `$page_type`.title
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't `LIMIT 1`, but there is only `$page_type` which matches the criteria. You join on `title` (why not on an id?) so there must only be one `$page_type` with images with a matching `title`.

If you want to return pages which also may not have any images then you need to change the `JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN`.

The way you link pages to images is flawed. If you change the title of a page you need to remember and update the respective title in the images table. In any case this is not a proper foreign key. You should use an auto_increment id on pages.